# How to put three comma separated Parameters into a Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have three parameters in my SP. Ids('1,2,3'), price('22,33.7,44'),count('4,5,1'). I also have Split function. Now, I want to insert these values in my database table. So my table will look like,

```
ID Price  Count
1   22     4
2   33.7   5
3   44     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL 2008 onwards, you can use [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) - I'd recommend trying that route so you can just pass a structured table in to your sproc. There's full examples in that MSDN link.

I'd prefer that route generally over CSV values/string splitting. I blogged here with a comparison of some different approaches & performance:  [Table Valued Parameters vs XML vs CSV](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html)

Comment: there's examples in both links. In your case, you would just have a single table valued parameter with 3 columns (ID, Price, Count)

Answer (score 1):

```
create function dbo.SimpleSplit(@str varchar(max))
returns @table table (
    val varchar(max),
    rowid int
)
with schemabinding
as
begin
    declare @pos int,
            @newPos int,
            @rowid int;
    set @pos = 1;
    set @newPos = charindex(',', @str, 1);
    set @rowid = 1;

    while (@newPos != 0)
    begin
        insert into @table
            values (substring(@str, @pos, @newPos - @pos), @rowid);

        set @rowid += 1;

        set @pos = @newPos + 1;
        set @newPos = charindex(',', @str, @pos);

        if (@newPos = 0)
            insert into @table
                values (substring(@str, @pos, len(@str)), @rowid);
    end

    return;
end
GO

create procedure somesp (@id varchar(128), @price varchar(128), @count varchar(128))
as
    select t.val as id, t2.val as price, t3.val as [count]
    from dbo.SimpleSplit(@id) t
    inner join dbo.SimpleSplit(@price) t2 on t.rowid = t2.rowid
    inner join dbo.SimpleSplit(@count) t3 on t.rowid = t3.rowid
GO

exec somesp '1,2,3', '22,33.7,44', '4,5,1'
```